# Cumulative distribution function in numpy not reaching 1?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a CDF over a histogram using matplotlib with the following code:

```
values, base = np.histogram(df['0'], bins=50)
cumulative = np.cumsum(values) / df['0'].sum()
# plot the cumulative function
plt.hist(df['0'], bins=50, density=True)
plt.plot(base[:-1], cumulative, c='blue')
plt.show()
```

However my plot ends up looking like this, where the CDF looks like it is nearing .007 or thereabouts, when I would expect it to reach 1:
[image: The plot I got]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Should `np.cumsum(values)` be equal to `df['0'].sum()`? Maybe you should calculate both values and print them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are normalizing the cumulative sum of the bins with the sum of the values in your dataframe. The quantity stored in `values` is the number of occurrence of `df['0']` inside the corresponding bin.

If you want to show the cumulative sum of the bins you need to normalize it to the total number of elements of `df['0']`:

```
cumulative = np.cumsum(values)/df['0'].values.shape[0]
```